# Is there a way to add proxied redhat maven repository to nexus?

Tags: maven, redhat, nexus

There is a situation that I cannot not resolve on my own. I have Sonatype Nexus™ 2.8.0-05 and I want to add redhat's public maven repository (http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all/) as a proxied repo. This repo does not have index, but I thought that should not be a problem.

So, I add it as a proxy repo, disable download of remote index (I've tried both ways, so this does not matter), other stuff I leave by default. I can see packages in "browse remote", but for some reason I can't see them while searching (i.e. 'org.jboss.as:jboss-as-security:jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14'). Also automatic routing does not work - "No scraper was able to scrape remote (or remote prevents scraping).".

Do anyone have a solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. What I did is I downloaded first jar manually through browser with link like: http://example.example:8081/nexus/content/repositories/jboss-org/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar . After first download repo begins to work.

Also, you should download a jar - first time i've pointed on folder, nexus gave me html as it was an artifact, and did not worked with that folder again until I removed this 'artifact' from nexus admin console.

This issue appeared not only redhat repo, but on others too.